# Complex chat message creation

Tags: java, swing, tcp, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am working on a program that has a chat function and i want it to be a little bit more than just text. I want to know what the best way is to show a custom complex message using JTextPane or something similar to show every time the client receives it.

Each message includes the following :

Divider(Thin grey line)

A picture (User Profile Picture)

A label (Username)

String (Custom Date)

String (Actual Message)

Divider(Thin grey line)

And it should look something like this :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH09i.png]

I don't care as much about how to specifically organize each component listed as much as how to make it work.

But my question is how do I group all of these into something that can be added over and over again every time a new message is sent?.

For example:

Should i use a scrollable JTextPane as the main container or something else, and then create a new JPanel for every message with a layout containing all the message components listed.

I know this might be a little confusing so if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: *"..if you have any questions feel free to ask."* Sure. Is there a *question* among those words above? If so, can you add a '?' at the end of it?

Comment: lol, asking questions without question marks... there.

Comment: *"how do I group all of these into something that can be added over and over again every time a new message is sent?"* Use a `JList`.